# Multisite, turn off "create new site"

Tags: multisite, customization

If someone enters the wrong URL to my wordpress multisite, they get the option to create another site in the network. Why does this happen, and how do I turn it off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This setting is controlled under: Network Admin > Settings > "Allow new registrations." You may want "Registration is disabled."

[image: Screenshot of "Allow new registrations" setting]